# Is it possible to restore OS X .dmg file to External Drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, restore, dmg

I recently traded in my iMac with 1TB HDD for a MacBook Pro with a 256 GB flash drive.

I want to restore my previous hard drive but obviously it won't fit on the new hard drive.

Is it possible to restore the .dmg *to* the external hard drive where the .dmg file resides? If not, how do I restore these files?

I have some very important files on there so I don't want to go testing something and then accidentally wiping that backup.

I *think* the attached image will do what I want but I would like to make 100% sure.

[image: restore image]

Answer (score 1):

No,You can NOT restore .dmg to the partition where the .dmg file resides.
However you can restore to another disk, or another partition in the same disk.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So would the screenshot I posted restore it on a new partition? Or would I have to setup a new partition first? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, from your screenshot I can't made the right judgement.

Answer (score 0):

It think you want to open Time Machine (activate it via the menu bar). You will get a window showing the files of the backup. From here it is possible to select the files you want to place back on your new mac.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I didn't use Time Machine to back up the disk I used Disk Utility. I can't find any way to use Time Machine to open a .dmg file.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the dmg file is stored on the external drive. The source and the target should not be the same. So you could:

Add an extra HD (let's call it ExtHDD2) and make sure you have an empty partition there.

Then your screenshot is ok but the target should be ExtHDD2, and the clean partition in that hard drive.

Once you restore the data, you wouldn't care anymore about the first external HD, and would take the files you need from ExtHDD2 to the main HD.

You could also just mount the dmg disk image and copy the files you need directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Migration Assistant**.

Go to Applications > Utilities.   Migration Assistant allowed you to import files settings from a Mac or Time Machine backup or even from a drive (dmg) that you specify.

See this [Apple Support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350).

See also [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/201840/120171).